# upgrading php to seven need advice

Tags: php

```
  <music>
    <?php
    if ($handle =  opendir('files/mp3')) {
      while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && substr($file,1) != '.') {
          $info = split("[.]", $file) ;    <- in php 7.4 split not supported i try with preg_split & str_split but don't return anything
          if(strtolower($info[1]) == "mp3"){
            echo "<song name='".htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($info[0]))."' />"; <- and here the "< stops the echo
          }
        }
      }
      closedir($handle);
    }
    ?>
  </music>
```

I have this code who searching for .mp3 files into a directory.
With php 5 this code was returning all the files from the directory as
<music name=each file and i get it from HTMLElement childnodes as "Element.childNodes[z].nodeName == "music" ->  Element.childNodes[z].attributes.name = the file name without the .mp3
I upgrade my php to 7.4 and this code no longer works.. i search it a bit, and before the

```
$info = split("[.]", $file)
```

it's echo the files in order without spaces.
I try with different ways preg_split, str_split i but can't make it..

Any help with this one in php 7.4 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `explode('.', $file);`

Comment: You should go to PHP 8.1, since 7.4 is quite old now.

Answer (score 0):

The function split was removed with PHP 7.0. You can use explode instead of split.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

Comment: Thank you all for the solutions! I already upgrade it to 8.1 and keep moving!